# Which episode marks the first appearance of Walt's hat in Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad

I found an article that said that the first appearance was in season 3, but Walt wore it in season 1 when he and Jesse met up with Tuco in the parking lot. I don't remember this being the first appearance, because doesn't he first look at it in his car or something?

Comment: I read that his putting on the hat in season 3 marks the emergence of Heisenberg, so it's a first in that respect.

Answer (score 9):

That was indeed the hat's first appearance. Season 1 episode 7 "A No-Rough-Stuff-Type Deal". Jesse even comments on it.

Comment: Is it that lex luther comment you are referring?

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Yep :)